# change everything on mouse hover CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the html code something like this:

```
<li class="sprite-ps2 wishlist">
<a href="/wishlist/">
My Wish
<br>
List
<p>
<i class="fa fa-list-alt fa-3x"></i>
</p>
</a>
</li>
```

I need to change background of **li** in blue color and everything inside of them to be color:white on mouse hover on the li element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/dv7bokwa/), you need to set background blue for `li:hover`, and `li:hover *` to be color white

```css
li:hover {
  background: blue;
}
li:hover,
li:hover * {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<li class="sprite-ps2 wishlist">
  <a href="/wishlist/">
My Wish
<br>
List
<p>
<i class="fa fa-list-alt fa-3x"></i>
</p>
</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in a <style> element or a .css file:

```
li:hover {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

Because all child elements inside <li> inherit the properties of their parent, they will have a white color (and a blue background too if they don't specify their own).